# Angular 2 Hash Routing strategy from rest api

Tags: php, rest, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

The issue with the routing is I'm using service to call data in JSON format from REST API. which is build in php side. And that's working perfectly it returns me something like this:

```
    [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "created_by": 1,
    "updated_by": 1,
    "created_at": 0,
    "updated_at": 0,
    "active": 1,
    "name": "MyCompany",
    "currency_id": null,
    "logo_img": null,
    "phone": null,
    "email": null,
    "website": null
  }
]
```

But while trying with hash location strategy I received the response of `index.html` instead of data from service.

http://apache:8080/MyCompany/backend/web/#/base/company

And this thing passes me the index with error:

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Because my service tries to convert the response data into JSON format (if not received in JSON format)

**boot.ts as follow:**

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS , 
          APP_BASE_HREF ,
          LocationStrategy,
          HashLocationStrategy
        } from 'angular2/router';


import { provide } from 'angular2/core';

import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})

]);
```

**my service method to get data:** 
Here base url points to my backend rest api from where it should be receiving response.

```
   getData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get( this.baseUrl + this.ReceivedUrl)
                    .map(response => response.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

**And binded it as:**

```
getCompany() {
        this.mainService.getData()      
                            .subscribe(
                            companys => this.companys = JSON.stringify(companys),
                            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        }
```

**Route Config:**

```
@RouteConfig([

    { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'base/res-company', name: 'Company', component: CompanyComponent },
])
```

**QUESTION:**
What m i doing wrong that i get html page rendered instead of json data of rest service by using hash location in url